# Flow type for Constructor function JSON arguments

Tags: flowtype

Using flow in a class definition, I need to type all of the class's properties:

```js
export default class Product {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  slug: string;
  featured: boolean;
  description: string;
  ...etc...
}
```

When I write my constructor function, I want it to accept an object that has the same shape as the type I just defined. How do I type that argument?

I could do it explicitly:

```js
constructor(json: {
    id: number,
    name: string,
    slug: string,
    featured: boolean,
    description: string,
    ...etc...
  }) {
    this.id = json.id
    this.name = json.name
    ...etc... 
  }
```

But that seems completely ridiculous and the obvious opposite of DRY. 
(To be honest, naming each property *within* the constructor method has always felt pretty un-DRY to me)

I can't just do `(json: Product)` because it's *not* an instance of `Product`, just an object with the same properties.

What is the right way to do this?